# How to reduce the image based on the windows size

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to reduce the image based on the windows size.Now I am using bootstrap to make the image content resize based on the window but the bootstrap loading the row images as column when reduce the size of the window but i need the images in row.how can i make it?

Comment: Welcome. Can you add some code where you try to edit the image?

Comment: Use this class in your <img> tag: 'img-responsive'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="image path" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well based on your question. You want to make an image full screen.
You can use this code

```
    #yourimage{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }
```

or put this in `<img src='' class='img-responsive'>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src=" " class=" " alt="">
```

In Bootstrap many image class `Img-responsive`,`img-thumbnail` and `img-rounded`. you access class according to your requirment.